# Setting default dropdown selection for model in Django admin interface

Tags: python, django, model, admin

Sorry if the title is hard to follow, I can't think of a concise way to word this.
In my Django project, I have five models, `ComputingObject`, `Laptop`, `Desktop`, `HardDrive`, and `SanitizationMethod`. They're linked as such:

```
class ComputingObject(models.Model):
    #various other fields...
    sanitize_method = models.ForeignKey(SanitizationMethod)

class Laptop(ComputingObject):
    #laptop-related fields

class SanitizationMethod(models.Model):
     description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Desktop and HardDrive also extend ComputingObject.

So in the admin interface, when creating a new instance of any of the three `ComputingObject` children, sanitize_method is shown as a drop-down (select) field. In my project, there are a small handful of `SanitizationMethod`s in the database. What I want is to have that drop-down menu default to a specific (different) choice for each of the three `ComputingObject` children. For instance, `Desktop` might default to "Remove hard drives", `HardDrive` would be "Degauss and destroy", etc. Is there a way to do this with django?

On the surface it seems as easy as overriding the `sanitize_method` field for each of the three children, and putting `defualt= x` in each, but django disallows overriding parent fields, so this approach won't work.

I'm stumped. Does anyone know how to do this (or if it's even possible)?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to override `formfield_for_foreignkey` in your child models ModelAdmins, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey